# Google Sheets loop / iterate through only visible sheets

Tags: loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to iterate through **only visible** Google Sheets and run a code in each one, but can't seem to locate how I would do this...

I have the following code, which runs through all sheets, even hidden ones:

```
function loopTest() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var s in allsheets){
var sheet=allsheets[s]

//code to run here:
  sheet.getRange('B4').setValue('test');

  }
}
```

Can anyone please advise how I can exclude hidden sheets so the code only appies to visible sheets?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Here's a tip - if a sheet is hidden there must be a property somewhere on a sheet instance to indicate that status - so check the Sheets class in the documentation for that property and then once you find it filter your sheets array using that property.

Comment: Thanks, eneded up working it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution:-

```
function loopTest() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var s in allsheets){
var sheet=allsheets[s]

   //Test is sheet is not hidden
   if (sheet.isSheetHidden()!= true) {

   //if not hidden run some code     
   sheet.getRange('A10').setValue('Nailed it!');

       }    
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this helps someone in the future :)

Comment: There is one more optimization you can use...look up the filter function of the array class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow, could you please elaborate &/or give an example?